# MVC4 - Using standard <input> textboxes alongside HTML Helpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I like how MVC 4 generates the views with the HtmlHelpers already defined:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartId)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartId)
    </div>
```

But for one field I added a jQuery autocomplete and now the textbox has taken the form of a standard input field:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input type="text" id="parts" name="parts" />
    </div>
```

When I Create the object (save the form) the Parts field is not brought in as a part of the new object.  How can I pair this field up with the other auto generated HTML Helpers so it saves correctly?  Here's my controller for reference however I'm hoping this can be accomplished in the page itself:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Part part)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(part);
    }
```

The Part class, which is a child object on the form.  The user will key in the MatchCode into the form but the page needs to save the Part object:

```
public partial class Part
{
    public Part()
    {
        this.Counts1 = new HashSet<Count>();
    }

    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public string Matchcode { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Count> Counts1 { get; set; }
}
```

The Count class is the main Parent class:

```
public partial class Count
{
    public System.Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> LocationId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> PartId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.Guid> UnitId { get; set; }
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }   
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
    public virtual Part Part { get; set; }
    public virtual Unit Unit { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `Part` class please?

Comment: thanks, so which property is your `parts` textbox meant to map to?

Comment: It's supposed to map to MatchCode.  The user will key in MatchCode.

Comment: @dankeshawn You need to use "matchcode" as the input's `name` attribute, then (instead of "parts").

Comment: @AntP Thanks, but Part is a child class on the page.  How to store the child object from a parent class?

Comment: You'll have to use "part.matchcode" then. I'm still not sure what's preventing you from using helpers here, though.

Comment: @AntP If I change `<input type="text" id="parts" name="parts" />` to `<input type="text" id="part.MatchCode" name="part.MatchCode" />` that means I have to change `$('#parts')` to `$('#part.MatchCode')` in my jQuery stement and then the AutoComplete doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @dankeshawn You don't need to change the ID, only the name, which is what is sent as the form field identifier in the POST and thus what MVC uses to bind. I can't help you with why the jQuery stops working since I have no information on how that works.

Comment: @dankeshawn, `id="part.MatchCode"` is not valid for use in jquery selector. If should be `id="part_MatchCode"` if you were to do it manually. But **dont**. Use `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Part.MatchCode)` and then `$('#Part_MatchCode')` in the jquery (look at the html generated by the helpers - it replaces the dot character with an underscore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part:

> But for one field I added a jQuery autocomplete and now the textbox has taken the form of a standard input field:

does not make sense.

Nothing stops you from using an HTML helper and then applying a jQuery autocomplete to that.

All you need is the `id` of the control, which you can provide yourself

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PartId, new { id = "parts" })
```

so that you have a hard-coded id string to pass to jQuery, or the other way round, pass the id MVC selects to jQuery without knowing what it was:

```html
<script>
    $("#@Html.IdFor(model => model.PartId)").autocomplete();
</script>
```

If you want to keep the `EditorFor` as opposed to `TextBoxFor`, you can do that too:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PartId, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "parts" }})
```

but then you have to make sure your editing template actually renders a text field.

You can use the "standard input textbox" too:

```
<input type="text" id="@Html.IdFor(model => model.PartId)" name="@Html.NameFor(model => model.PartId)" />
```

Comment: this helped me, thank you.  I wasn't clear when I said that adding the autocomplete made the textbox a standard input field.  I should have said the tutorial I followed used a standard input field and my question was how to revert back to the HtmlHelper without losing the autocomplete functionality (not knowing if it was possible).  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The HtmlHelpers end up rendering normal HTML so there is no difference between the HTML rendered by 'standard input fields' and that rendered by the HtmlHelpers.

If you can make your code pass all the right arguments to the controller using the helpers then you should be able to 'view source' in your browser and copy that HTML into your view. If you do that then the values that end up passed to the controller should be the same, as long as the HTML the browser receives is the same in both circumstances then the calls to the controller should be the same.

Comment: This doesn't provide a complete answer to the question, only "general guidance," which belongs in comments, not answers. Once you have reached 50 reputation you will be able to leave comments.

Answer (score 0):

> Part is a child class on the page. How to store the child object from
>   a parent class

So ...

```
@model Mvc.Models.YouParentModel

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Part.PartId)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Part.Matchcode, , new { id = "autocompleteField" })
    </div>
```

Then in your your javascript code you attach autocompleter to **$("#autocompleteField")**

For example:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    $( "#autocompleteField" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Or simpler `@Html.TextBoxFor => m.Part.Matchcode)` and `$( "#Part_Matchcode" ).autocomplete({ ...` (just use the ID generated by the helper)